# count frequency of vector elements

Tags: vector

I have this code which gives the number of occurrences of each element of `w vector` in `vector y`

```
a= [7     4     9     6     4    10     9     6     7     6]
y=zeros(size(a));
for i=1:length(a)
    y(i)=sum(a==a(i));
end
y = y;
end
 y=[2     2     2     3     2     1     2     3     2     3]
```

but this result is not enough because I need to know the index along with the number of repartitions. The result should look like:

```
element no of repartitions  position1  position2 position3  
  7           2                1           9        0
  4           2                2           5        0
  9           2                3           7        0
  6           3                4           8        10
  10          1                0           0        0
```

Comment: You're going to get a lot of thumb-downs. I'd suggest you re-organize your question. Also, make sure you quote your code.

Comment: Please edit the tags to include what language environment you're using (I'm assuming Matlab or Octave.)